# Split ticks on y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have drawn a heatmap, but it looks like this:

[image]

As you see all ticks on y axis are covering each other and all in all it doesn't look good. How could I separate these ticks from each other on y axis?
My code is:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Date, Place`)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = N)) +
  scale_fill_viridis(name = N, label = comma) +
  theme_tufte(base_family = "Helvetica") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0.2,0))
```

I tried to change scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0.2,0)) to scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0.7,0)), but nothing changed. i can't decrease number of objects on y axis

Data sample:

```
Date        Place          N
2020.04.20  8797    173032
2020.05.01  315D    10
2020.04.13  Q168    193597
2020.04.19  8797    96104
2020.04.02  8797    244935
2020.04.04  315D    474049
2020.05.01  8797    13
2020.04.23  315D    125607
2020.04.18  Q168    787224
2020.04.11  8797    282303
2020.04.12  8797    138443
2020.04.24  Q168    176487
2020.03.19  315D    290053
2020.04.10  315D    561935
2020.04.06  Q168    221196
2020.03.26  Q168    202552
2020.03.23  315D    516936
2020.04.06  315D    195038
```

Comment: please provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput(head(df))`

Comment: @mnist i added sample data

Comment: @mnist i don't that problem will be visible on small sample, cause in original data there are several thousands of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you planning to export your data? If so, I like to fix any scaling issues at that step.

```
ggsave(my_plot, filename = "plot.pdf", scale = 0.5)
ggsave(my_plot, filename = "plot.pdf", width = 10, height = 10, units = "in")
```

You can replace "pdf" with pretty much any file format.

Comment: im going to knit it into html, i write in in rdp

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with knit

Comment: well i can add img file in html then, can i turn it into image?

Comment: Yes, you can `ggsave` the plot to your computer and then add the image to your html. You won't lose any quality if you used a vectorized format like PDF. There might be a more elegant solution but this will get you the same result

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions adjusting the y-axis guide. I'm sorry for not using your data, I couldn't easily paste it into my R session.

The first option is to not display labels that are overlapping. You can do this with setting `check.overlap = TRUE` in the axis guide.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, paste0(Species, "_", 1:150))) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(y = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE))
```

[image]

The second option is to 'dodge' the labels, i.e. place labels in a hierarchy, the depth of which is controlled by `n.dodge`.

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, paste0(Species, "_", 1:150))) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(y = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: it says could not find function guide_axis

Comment: i have a ggplot2 version 3.2.1, is there any solution for that version?

Comment: No, not a convenient one at least. They updated how the guides work in v3.3.0, so this doesn't work on lower versions.